# Javascript Remove Negative Decimal Value From String

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to remove the negative and positive decimal value from the string following script remove the positive decimal value from the string however negative is not working

```js
var string = "Test Alpha -0.25 (1-3)"
string = string.replace(/\s*\d+[.,]\d+/g, "");
console.log(string);
```

above code is returning following output:

```
Test Alpha - (1-3)
```

Expected output:

```
Test Alpha (1-3)
```

Please help me

Comment: try matching a `-` ... like `/\s*-?\d+` etc

Comment: is the structure always the same? like your string = String Number Number ?

Comment: thank you /\s*-?\d+[.,]\d+/g this pattern works @Bravo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign should be optional (`?`), and then you can match a set of numbers followed by a `.` or a `,`, followed by another set of numbers, and replace that match. That way you can match both positive and negative numbers with the same expression.

```js
var string = "Test Alpha 0 -0.25 12,31 31 -123.45 (1-3)"
string = string.replace(/( -?\d+([.,]\d+)?)/g, '');
console.log(string);
```

Comment: hi andy thank you how to remove 0 example Test Alpha 0 (1-3)

Comment: @DocuStack Updated. Just make everything from the decimal point a new group, and make that optional too.

Answer (score 2):

You need add the "-" in the regrex condition.

```js
var string = "Test Alpha -0.25 (1-3)"
string = string.replace(/\s*-\d+[.,]\d+/g, "");
console.log(string);
```

Comment: thank you how to remove 0 example `Test Alpha 0 (1-3)`?

Comment: Try with this, https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org

Answer (score 0):

Change the regex statement to match the `-`, this can be like so:

`/\s*-\d+[.,]\d+/g`